# Invalid Swift Support - The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, app-store

All working proper for 2 days ago.

Now when I am adding build for external testing Appstore connect it said invalid binary. I am using flutter for app development.

ITMS-90433: Invalid Swift Support - The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just modify the code signature of libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

I am using flutter 1.22.4 and Xcode 12.3 for development.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, solved by changing ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES to YES in my project configuration.

In Xcode select your project -> Build Settings and look for "Always embed swift standard libraries". If NO is selected, switch to YES (for debug and release), and it's done.

I recommend cleaning your build in Xcode before building and submitting again, just to make sure you have no residues of your old build left!

Comment: I have already set ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES to Yes but still get the same error.

Comment: for me, cleaning the project in xcode and rebuilding worked.