# App Store not accepting my new app version written in React Native which was earlier written in Swift

Tags: swift, react-native, expo

I created an app using expo cli. I also created the build for the same using expo server and was trying to upload the app to the app store.
However, the previous version of the same app was written in Swift and I get this error.
As a result Apple is rejecting my app.
I have maintained the same bundle Id of the app.
[image]

Error :

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for your app, "My App Name". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90433: Invalid Swift Support - The file libswiftAVFoundation.dylib doesn’t have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just modify the code signature of libswiftAVFoundation.dylib.

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024969/invalid-swift-support-the-file-libswiftavfoundation-dylib-doesn-t-have-the-cor) they suggest to set the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`to `YES`. Did you tried that already?

Answer (score 0):

solved by changing `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to `YES` in my project configuration.

In XCode **select your project -> Build Settings** and look for "**Always embed swift standard libraries**". If NO is selected, switch to **YES** (for debug and release), and it's done.

It is recommended to clean your build in Xcode before building and submitting again, just to make sure you have no residues of your old build left!

**Solution 2**:

The other solution I came across is the version mix match. Make sure you are using correct version of expo. Otherwise just update it to the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this solution works because when the application is built on Expo, using the command EAS, is the expo server who creates the IPA, and in one step copy the file libswiftCore.dylib (in my case) and is signing it using "codesign", then making changes in the local Xcode I don't expect solve this problem. ¿Maybe making some change that allows the project tell expo which signature must use in the swift support file?

thanks

Comment: If that is the case then he need to connect correct Xcode version s developer tool

Comment: But the xcode libraries are part of the build in Expo.. I think that you can't choose it... One step building the app in expo.dev is copy the file from server environment to the generated IPA and sign it using codesign, but I don't know how to change the key that is used in expo.dev with codesign... 
The step is in the build log "CopySwiftLibs...." and then "usr/bin/codesign --force --sign .........."

Comment: Did a thorough RnD here and figured out that there is nothing to do with which codebase you use to create your IPA build as long as the build metadata matches, it can be accepted on the store no matter which language you prefer to write your code in.
All I had to do was upgrade my expo to the latest version and create a new build and it was accepted on the store.
Keeping this here for others, if someone faces this problem in near future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).